# Modify Ubuntu 14.04 'Connect to Server' source code

Tags: source-code

I want to wirelessly connect some Ubuntu 14.04 laptops to a network share which requires authentication. If I open up a Nautilus window and click Connect to Server in the side panel I can successfully find the server, but when it prompts me for authentication, it fails without giving me any error ( it just prompts me for authentication again). I want to edit the source code of the Connect to Server program so that it gives useful error messages and I can tell where it's failing. How would I go about doing this? I have never needed to change an Ubuntu program before so I don't know where to start.

Do I need to download the Connect to Server source code from somewhere, modify it, and then recompile it into the right directory? Or is it just a bash script somewhere that I can change on the fly? Any help welcome.